# How to only make page accessible if user is logged in using php

Tags: php, html, authentication

I am working on a website that has a login form. The user can enter the information, and if it is wrong, the site sends an alert. However, the problem is that you can easily go to the page after you login by changing the name in the address bar.

You can easily enter the page without logging in, so this is bad. Can you please help?

validation.php:

```
<?php

$name =$_POST['user'];
$pass =$_POST['password'];
//Test code
//echo $pass; 
//End Test Code

//Connection Code
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 
mysqli_select_db($con, 'userregistration');
// Connection End

//Query Code

$s = "select * from usertable where name = '$name' and password = '$pass'";
//test
//echo $s;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){

    echo "Hello " . $name;

}
else{

   echo "<script>";
   echo "alert('Incorrect Username or Password');";
   echo "window.location.replace('login.html');";
   echo "</script>";

}

?>
<!--html code-->
```

Donate.php

```
<center><h1>Donate Here!</h1></center>
```

Comment: `if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) { exit('Sign in to view this page!') }` - Example of what needs to be done, I'm sure you could piece the rest together.

Comment: Also please secure your application. **Never** store passwords unencrypted in your database. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injections. Wich means that a hacker can get in your database and steal the information in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set some kind of marker into your session to mark fact that your user is authenticated (logged in). You may store user_id of current user in `$_SESSION['current_user_id']`.

Please also note that your query is good target to sql injection, so do not forget to SQL escape any data you add to sql query via `mysqli_real_escape_string`

validation.php:

```
//...
$s = "select * from usertable where name = '"
     .mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name).
     "' and password = '"
     .mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $pass)
     ."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
  // row fecthed, user found
  $user_id = $row['user_id']; // Let expect that usertable has user_id column
  $_SESSION['current_user_id'] = $user_id;
}
else
{
   echo "<script>";
   echo "alert('Incorrect Username or Password');";
   echo "window.location.replace('login.html');";
   echo "</script>";
   exit();
}
//...
```

On all your pages, on the very begin put the code:

some_page.php:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['current_user_id'])) { exit('Your session expiried!') }
//... do some stuff
```

To logout your user, you may just unset `$_SESSION['current_user_id']`

logout.php:

```
unset($_SESSION['current_user_id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create session after successful login:

```
session_start();

if ($num == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $name;
}
```

Now in your Donate.php check if user is logged in by checking if session is set:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    // no session, redirect user to index.php
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Should it not be `isset` instead of `isSet`?

Comment: I've used it both ways. Never have had any problems. If there is any reason why you shouldn't use it like this, I would be happy to know ;)

Comment: PHP is case-insensitive for function names.

Comment: No doubt it is case-insensitive, but you should make it a habit of using the functions the way there are defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict Donate.php try this

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if (empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        header('Location:login.php');
    } ?>

<center><h1>Donate Here!</h1></center>
```

Comment: hello, I tried this it worked. However, If I enter the right information in the login form, it still redirects me back to login.html. No matter what I do, it still redirects me back. How do I fix?